# How to remove/ignore unexpected keyword arguments when passing as dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, keyword-argument, argument-unpacking

The following code

```
def f(par1, par2):
    print("par1 = %s, par2 = %s" % (str(par1), str(par2)))

pars = {
    'par1': 12,
    'par2': 13,
    'par3': 14
}

f(**pars)
```

raises error

```
TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'par3'
```

How to either ignore `par3` or find, that it is unexpected and pop it from dictionary programmtically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get functions arguments with `__code__.co_varnames`

```
expected = {key: pars[key] for key in f.__code__.co_varnames}
f(**expected)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could define your function to accept keyword arguments like:

```
def f(par1, par2, **kwargs):
    print("par1 = %s, par2 = %s" % (str(par1), str(par2)))
```